# Unable to connect to Cloud object storage instance IBM Watson Studio

Tags: ibm-watson, data-science-experience, watson-studio, ibm-cloud-storage

I am trying to connect to COS from IBM Watson studio but I get an error...

[image]

When I hit enter I get the following error:

```
Unable to find products data_catalog or data_science_experience in the 
entitlements response for account id: 51373fa1b8bf36fd9d78574d19af0d11.
```

Comment: I am getting the same error with the following after the account id:
"if you are using Beta release of Watson Studio or Watson Knowledge Catalog service, delete the Beta service instance and re-create it in order to use GA version."

I don't know if you are seeing that or not, but I hope it is helpful. I am not using a beta version so i'm unsure how to proceed